# Python: __import__ works in REPL, but not in a script

Tags: python, module

I'm quite confused here. I have a directory `root` with a subdirectory `foo` containing a file `__init__.py`. If I run the following in the python REPL from `root`, it works fine:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('foo')
>>> print __import__('foo')
<module 'foo' from 'foo/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

However, if I put the same commands into a script `root/import_foo.py`, it fails:

```
import os
os.chdir('foo')
print __import__('foo')


> python import_foo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    print __import__('foo')
ImportError: No module named foo
```

Why the discrepancy? How can I correct this?

Comment: Maybe replace `os.chdir` with `sys.path.append`.

Comment: Its probably related to the relative locations of the files involved.  Try placing ```print os.getcwd()``` at the start of each case and post  the output

Comment: @wnnmaw they're both the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's been long since asked, but I just lost an hour on this problem, and the solution is to sys.path.append(".") after os.chdir;

Full story:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2004-June/023835.html

> In Python 2.3a2 in non-interactive mode an import after an os.chdir
>   does not import the module in the new current directory after the
>   os.chdir.  Instead it attempts to import a module (if present) by that
>   name in the previous current directory before the os.chdir. If there
>   is not a module by that name in the previous current directory, there
>   is an ImportError exception.

```
$ mkdir -p some/dir/with/python/
$ cat > some/dir/with/python/example.py
x = 17
$ cat > import_test.py
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("some/dir/with/python")        
m = __import__("example")
print(m)
os.chdir(cwd)
$ python3 import_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "import_test.py", line 4, in <module>
m = __import__("example")
ImportError: No module named 'example'
```

BUT:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("some/dir/with/python")
>>> __import__("example")
<module 'example' from '/tmp/some/dir/with/python/example.py'>
>>>
```

And with "." in sys.path:

```
$ cat > import_test.py
import sys
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("some/dir/with/python")  
sys.path.append(".")
m = __import__("example")
print(m)
os.chdir(cwd)
$ python3 import_test.py
<module 'example' from './example.py'>
$
```